# How to get permissions from other file js in react

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, permissions, roles

I have fetched the following data from the `server` and stored it in `Redux`

```js
[
    {
        "resourceId": 1,
        "resourceAction": "UserInsert",
        "resourceController": "Home",
        "resourceTitle": "ثبت کاربر"
    },
    {
        "resourceId": 4,
        "resourceAction": "ChangePassword",
        "resourceController": "Home",
        "resourceTitle": "تغییر کلمه عبور"
    },
    {
        "resourceId": 5,
        "resourceAction": "UserEdit",
        "resourceController": "Home",
        "resourceTitle": "ویرایش کاربر"
    },
    {
        "resourceId": 6,
        "resourceAction": "UserDelete",
        "resourceController": "Home",
        "resourceTitle": "حذف کاربر"
    },
    {
        "resourceId": 18,
        "resourceAction": "*",
        "resourceController": "*",
        "resourceTitle": "همه"
    }
]
```

I want write all conditions in a seprate js file and use each condition result in components.

> my persmission.js file is

```js
//REDUX IMPORT
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from "react-redux";

//redux data
const permissions = useSelector((state) => state.permissions.data);

export const canAll = permissions.resourceController == '*';
export const canInsertUser = (permissions.resourceAction == 'UserInsert' && permissions.resourceController == 'Home') || canAll;
```

How can i export each condition's result and use in other components?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a custom hook which is called `usePermission`. This hook will get a permission as a `enum` and return a `bool` value as a result. Also there is a problem in this line of code which I've updated it:

```
const permissions = useSelector((state) => state.permissions.data); //=> permssions is array and you can not use it like this : permissions.resourceController
```

Here's the sample implementation of the functionality which you need:

```
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from "react-redux";

export const permissionEnum = Object.freeze({
        canAll: 'canAll',
        canInsertUser: 'canInsertUser',
        //... => other permissions
});

export const usePermission = () =>
{
   const permissionArray = [];
   const permissions = useSelector((state) => state.permissions.data);
   if(permissions.some((permission) => permission.resourceController == '*'))
     permissionArray.push(permissionEnum.canAll);
   if(permissions.some((permission) => (permissions.resourceAction == 'UserInsert' && permissions.resourceController == 'Home'))
     permissionArray.push(permissionEnum.canInsertUser);
   //... => other conditions
  
  return permissionArray;
}

export const hasPermission = (permissionValue) =>
{ 
  const permissions = usePermission();
  return permissions.some((permission)=> permission == permissionValue);
}
```

So, you can use it in a sample component like this:

```
import { usePermission, hasPermission, permissionEnum } from './permission.js';

const SampleComponent = (props) =>
{
   // if you just need all permissions in an array :
   const permissions = usePermission();
   // if you need check a specific permission : 
   const canAll = hasPermission(permissionEnum.canAll);
   //...
}
```